# MsTest parallelization

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, mstest

Im running two tests that share resources in parrallel.

I expected that the Test1 would fail, however it turned out that MsTestV2 creates a new instance of the test class and therefore the member variable is not shared.

This is verified by checking the object hashcode for each test, and also check how many time the constructor is called.

```
[TestClass]
public class ParallelizationTest
{
    private int psw = 0;

    public ParallelizationTest()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Ctor: ParallelizationTest");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Test1 started with HashCode: " + GetHashCode());
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Assert.AreEqual(psw, 0);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Test1 ended");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Test2 started with HashCode: " + GetHashCode());
        psw = 123;
        Assert.AreEqual(psw, 123);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Test2 ended");
    }
}
```

The MsTestV2 is configured as (*Workers is set to **2***):

```
  <RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
    <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
    <DisableParallelization>false</DisableParallelization>
    <TestSessionTimeout>1000000</TestSessionTimeout>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <MSTest>
    <Parallelize>
      <Workers>2</Workers>
      <Scope>MethodLevel</Scope>
    </Parallelize>
  </MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

Is creating a new instance of the test class guaranteed by the MsTest framework?

Comment: Why not try it with a larger number of tests?

Comment: I can try with 1000+ and it still would t answer my question I think.
It could be my setup, OS or any other thing that could influence it.

Comment: You've got 2 worker threads set up there, so what would happen is two threads get fed test methods. Feeding two threads 1000 test methods should help you make an educated guess I think. I haven't tried it but I'd expect two class instances to still be used, and assume that the dev choosing `MethodLevel` means the dev guarantees (to himself) there won't be any res sharing. I can't find any sort of written documentation by Microsoft that says "each parallelized test method gets its own class instance", so the only real way to answer is to look into the MSTest sources, which can change later on.

Comment: So no, I don't think this is guaranteed to happen, not until Microsoft states it and becomes documented behavior that won't change unexpectedly in future versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSTest creates a new instance of the [TestClass] for each test method. That behaviour continues with MSTestV2 as well. .runsettings does not affect this behaviour.
Please consider filing a issue on the [MSTestV2 doc repo](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx-docs) to get the documentation clarified.

Comment: Do you know what is the purpose of having the TestInitialize? I cant come up with any good reason of having TestInitializer. not even for backward compatibility.

Comment: See here for some commentary: https://daedtech.com/in-defense-of-test-setup-methods/